# Edit multiple columns in a line using awk command?

Tags: shell, awk

I'm trying to edit 3 columns in a file if the value in column 1 equals a specific string. This is my current attempt:

```
cp file file.copy
awk -F':' 'OFS=":" { if ($1 == "root1") $2="test"; print}' file.copy>file
rm file.copy
```

I've only been able to get the awk command working with one column being changed, I want to be able to edit $3 and $8 as well. Is this possible in the same command? Or is it only possible with separate awk commands or with a different command all together?

Edit note: The real command i'll be passing variables to the columns, i.e. $2=$var

It'll be used to edit the /etc/passwd file, sample input/output:

```
root:$6$fR7Vrjyp$irnF38R/htMSuk0efLSnAten/epf.5v7gfs0q.NcjKcFPeJmB/4TnnmgaAoTUE9.n4p4UyWOgFwB1guJau8AL.:17976::::::
```

Comment: [edit] your question to show us the code where you tried to edit `$3` and it failed and tell us in what way it failed. Also include concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: After the edit, try `awk -v var1="$v1" -v var2="$v2" -F':' '$1 == "root1" { $2 = var1; $3 = var2}1' FS=":"  file > tmp && mv tmp file`.

Comment: Dear AceVenturos, you seem to have a perfectly running command and your request is rather a straightforward adjustment of the existing command. With a bit of reading about awk you would be able to make the adjustment yourself in minutes. While I strongly support your quest for knowledge, please be advised that Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. If you want to know more about awk, which I strongly recommend as it is a great tool to know, have a look at https://catonmat.net/awk-one-liners-explained-part-one

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you, I appreciate it!

Comment: @kvantour Thank you, that's on me, my patience has been thin the last few days but I'll do more research in the future. Appreciate the link!

Comment: Under where you say `sample input/output` you only posted 1 line of text - whether that's the input or the output, provide the other. Also remember to post the code you wrote to update $3 so we can help you fix it. From what you've posted so far I strongly suspect your real problem has nothing to do with modifying another field and is instead related to the one real code snippet you did provide - `$2=$var` (note the `$` in `$var` folks).

Answer (score 2):

You can create multiple statements for the if condition with a block {}.

```
awk -F':' 'OFS=":" { if ($1 == "root1") {$2="test"; $3="test2";} print}' file.copy>file
```

You can also improve your command by using awk's default "workflow": `condition{commands}`. For this you need to bring the OFS to the input variables (-v flag)

```
awk -F':' -v OFS=":" '$1=="root1"{$2="test"; $3="test2"; print}' file.copy>file
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
# Fake sample values
v1=pass1
v2=pass2
awk -v var1="$v1" -v var2="$v2" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} $1 == "root1" { $2 = var1; $3 = var2}1' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

See the [online `awk` demo](https://ideone.com/TbmrU0):

```
s="root1:xxxx:yyyy
root11:xxxx:yyyy
root1:zzzz:cccc"
v1=pass1
v2=pass2
awk -v var1="$v1" -v var2="$v2" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} $1 == "root1" { $2 = var1; $3 = var2}1' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
root1:pass1:pass2
root11:xxxx:yyyy
root1:pass1:pass2
```

Note:

- `-v var1="$v1" -v var2="$v2"` pass the variables you need to use in the awk command
- `BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}` set the field separator
- `$1 == "root1"` check if Field 1 is equal to some value
- `{ $2 = var1; $3 = var2 }` set Field 2 and 3 values
- `1` calls the default `print` command
- `file > tmp && mv tmp file` helps you "shrink" the "replace-inplace-like" code.